# Return true only if all array elements exist

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following array `[681, 845, 787, 681]`. I want to return true only if both 681 and 845 are present. I feel like this should work:

```
registered_courses # => [681, 845, 787, 681]
registered_courses.all? {[842, 681]} # => true
```

I would have expected this to return false since 842 does not exist in the array.

Comment: Why would you expect that? Ruby is mostly intuitive, but you can't just throw _anything_ at it and it'll read your mind. Have you visited documentation page for `Enumerable#all?`?

Comment: What should it return for `[1,2,3]` and `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are using [`.all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) incorrectly
2. Your logic is backward, you really want to test if all of the courses you want to see (e.g. [842, 681]) are in `registered_courses`

   `[842, 681].all? { |course| registered_courses.include?(course) }`

Answer (score 1):

Considering the following:

```
courses = [842, 681]
registered_courses = [681, 845, 787, 681]
```

you can reverse the logic using an `all?` approach:

```
courses.all? { |course| registered_courses.include?(course) } 
# => false
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/repls/ExtraneousLameMetrics)

or you can also use `-` with `empty?`:

```
(courses - registered_courses).empty?
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/repls/HoneydewSphericalAutocad)

Comment: @mudasobwa: which one and why exactly do you have such a strong conviction?

Comment: Try `courses = [842] * 2`. Not all the elements from `courses` are presented in the `registered` array (the second one does not.)

Comment: if me are talking about the presence in the same count, than yes, yet it depends on the OP if it should be a matter of caution

Answer (score 1):

The non-uniq elements version:

```
a = [681, 845, 787, 681]
b = [681, 842]
a_mudasobwa = a.inject(Hash.new(0)){|h, el| h[el]+= 1; h}
b_mudasobwa = b.inject(Hash.new(0)){|h, el| h[el]+= 1; h}
p b_mudasobwa.all?{|k,v| a_mudasobwa[k] >= v} # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `&` operator, i.e.

```
courses = [842, 681]
(courses & registered_courses) == courses
```

The `&` simply returns the data in common in both arrays; if this matches what you desire then you've got your answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa: probalby not a concern, seeing these look like course ids.

Comment: That was my thinking - it doesn't seem you can register for the same course twice. But that is an assumption, so happy to update / delete based on the poster's response to your comment @mudasobwa.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the arrays, that way you'll know which elements are not present:

```
a = [681, 845, 787, 681]
b = [681, 842]
b - a # => [842]
```